# Why is my account renewed

Tags: support, deleted-users

It has been little since I visited my SO account my earlier account was

[image: Account with early activities]

when I wanted to Login I faced a scenario as I'm new user, system was asking permissions and so on and so forth.
I was a user with 15+ reputation but when I logged in got 1 reputation on my account looks like as I'm new SO user.
I wanted to ask this question earlier but wasn't able because asking question here requires 5+ reputation and I got only 1.
Wanna Ask is there any fault with my login info or some in thing other, it is quit confusing.

Comment: Do you remember your original account's credentials?

Comment: Yeah and see my edit showing recent achievements as well in a snapshot.

Comment: That doesn't say anything about a *previous* account, though.

Comment: I mean to say that I have got some privileges which are still showing in recent achievements menu.

Comment: Yes, but none of those privileges indicate to me that you had an account with any higher reputation than maybe 5.

Comment: O Man! please take a look at second item in list of achievements menu

Comment: That is _Vote Up_ privilege which requires 15+ reputation!!

Comment: I don't see any answers or questions on your account that would indicate anything else, either - maybe you answered a question which was accepted, but then the question was deleted?  I can't tell you what's going on based on this little information alone...

Comment: That is the issue I'm facing here, when I got to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370248/replacing-simplecursoradapter-with-child-of-cursoradapter, which I asked on SO it is saying __Page Not Found__ my questions are disappeared.

Comment: Okay, I can see *that* at least.  So it looks like the account was deleted after the question was removed by the Community user.  As for why?  That's a matter I leave for the mods to divine.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get, what do you mean by _leave for the mods to divine_?

Comment: I can't answer why your earlier account was deleted, but at least now we know that you *had* an earlier account.  Only the moderator staff would be able to tell you.

Comment: OK that is So nice of you that you you agree that I had an earlier account! but ... why it was deleted it is a _fantasy_ for now and then!

Answer (score 18):

Your account was deleted as a [sockpuppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)); because together with two other accounts your account voted for another *user*, not their content.

If you are, in fact, an actual person and not a fake account, you need to stop voting for your friends. While we encourage everyone to upvote great posts, the motivation for doing so needs to be anchored in the merits of the *post*, **not the person who wrote it.** Your voting behaviour made you indistinguishable from a fake account.

Stack Exchange works by ensuring that the best information rises to the top. Voting specifically for content that benefits your friends, family or colleagues unfairly skews that system, and continuing to do so can result in a lengthy suspension for all involved.